# Can I use Firefox developer toolbar commands in my addon?

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-developer-tools

I am developing a Firefox addon for making fullpage screenshots of web pages. I know that several good addons that do this are already available, but we have some specific needs so I thought I would try to make my own.

I read that I can do `screenshot --fullpage` in the [Firefox Developer Toolbar](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/GCLI#Commands). This seems to works well. Can I also call this command from within my addon? If so, how would I go about that?

Comment: Yes you can, I don't know how though I would have to look into it. But absolutely yes you can. If that was the verification you were looking for to start looking that go for it. I know I like to get an answer on "is it possible or not" before digging and wasting my time. If you don't find it let us know we'll help you find it. But the answer is yes this is absolutely possible. And although digging and finding that probably is more work then just making your own canvas and doing `ctx.drawWindow`.

Comment: Thank you. This is very good to know. I don't understand how to do it though. I can find lots of good info on developing addons and resources on using the ff developer toolbar but nothing on combining the two.

Comment: The stuff we need is in here: https://dxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/toolkit/devtools/gcli/commands/screenshot.js#70 thats firefox's code base for nightly

Comment: I have not figured this out, but I _did_ finally realize that the Developer Toolbar command `screenshot --fullpage` is just a shortcut to javascript code that makes a canvas and calls `ctx.drawWindow`, like you mentioned. I had somehow assumed that the Developer Toolbar was a kind of interface to low level, core Firefox C++ code. I thought using it would be more efficient than making a canvas. 
Since my assumption turns out to be completely wrong, I am dropping this idea.